# ES6 При создании объекта при помощи дублированных имён свойств

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

В ES6 объекте можно создать дублированные имена свойств такие как a = {x:1, x:2, x:3, x:4}; , так вот если я в консоли вывожу console(a.x) // вывод 4. Если я хочу взять 1, 2 или 3 значени что мне делать?

Comment: Ничего. Их там нет. Хотите несколько значений создавайте массив

Comment: `{ x: [1, 2, 3, 4] }`

Comment: Спасибо за чудесную логику. Буду в курсе что так можно делать.

Comment: @ErickHack дело не ES6 это json. можно задать вот так: `a = [{x:1},{x:2},{x:3},{x:4}]` и обращатся по индексу `a[1].x` (вернет 2) тоже самое и с примером выше от entithat

Comment: @Greg-- как это может быть json-ном объясните пожалуйста.
Ваш пример выглядит крутым но пример с entithat мне кажется лучшим)

Comment: @entithat json это метод записи ключ: значение, в принципе мой массив - это валидный json и так же это массив и вернет `true` если проверить `Array.isArray([{ x: 1 }, { x: 2 }, { x: 3 }, { x: 4 }]);` Как записывать вы сами для себя выбираете, в моей записи это отдельные элемены, которые могут иметь кроме ключа x другие ключи например `a = [{x:1, y: true},{x:2},{x:3},{x:4}] ` , в случае x: [...] - x это ключ значение которого - массив. Вы сами должны понять какие данные вы собираетесь сериализовать, это два правильных варианта если нет информации что должно происходить далее с переменной a

Comment: @ErickHack выше не того тегнул, я ссылаюсь на документацию по json [Массивы как JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON#%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA_json) т.е. запись по типу `{key: value}` и `[{key: value}]` - оба JSON, массив нужно использовать к примеру если это повторяющийся паттерн (карточка товара с ключами: цена, размер, цвет....)

Comment: @Greg-- спасибо теперь я понял что json это, синтаксис в виде объекта либо массив который имеет объект. Например [{id, className, elements}, и.т.д]. Ведь json документ превращается в json объект и наоборот. Не так ли? Спасибо заранее. Теперь ч понимаю что такое stackoverflow)